# Nuget not working for Microsoft.Bcl.Build

Tags: nuget-package-restore

For the command:

```
"NuGet.exe" install "C:\builddir\packages.config" -source "" -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "c:\solutiondir "
```

Microsoft.Bcl.Build gets error:
Unable to find version '1.0.21' of package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build'

but Microsoft.Bcl installs ok.  How do I find the reason Microsoft.Bcl.Build cannot be found. I tried other versions, same error.

Comment: Why do you have `-source ""`?

Comment: I grabbed what VS2015 put in the console when I was running msbuild. Another thing is that VS2015 restores the package. But I am creating a build process outside VS and I need the packages to restore from the command line.  I removed -source and got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio places a copy of nuget.exe in the project folder called .nuget, which has the version 2.8.5. A newer version can be found at [NuGet Distributions](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) which works. Put the newer version 3.4.3 in the project and nuget installs all the missing packages before msbuild runs.